# implementar servicios,implementar componentes

Tags: javascript, html5

implementar en "userService"(ya creado), todos los métodos para manejar la API de usuarios tienen que contener un obtener todos(get), un guardar(post) un modificar(put),un eliminar(delete),un obtener por id(get)

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

```js
private baseUrl = 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
constructor(private HTTP: HttpClient) {}
getUsuario(): Obsevable < Usuarios[] > {
  console.log(this.HTTP.get < Usuarios[] > (this.baseUrl + '/users'));
  return this.HTTP.get < Usuarios[] > (this.baseUrl + '/users');
}
}
```

Comment: nos muestras que llevas y que fallos o cosas no has logrado?

Comment: private baseUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/';
  constructor(private HTTP: HttpClient) { }
  getUsuario(): Obsevable<Usuarios[]> {
    console.log(this.HTTP.get<Usuarios[]>(this.baseUrl + '/users'));
    return this.HTTP.get<Usuarios[]>(this.baseUrl + '/users');
  }}

Comment: necesito saber como agregarle body a post y put?

Comment: ahí el get me lo toma bien, pero cuando ingreso el post me pide el body